# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support CISCO UCS

Tags: compatibility

I have (2) Cisco UCS 5108 Blade chassis with a total of (16) Cisco B200M3 Blades.  Each blade has (2) 10 Core Intel E5-2680 1866MHz CPUs.  Total environments resources 32 CPUs (320 Cores), 4096 GM Memory and 45TB of combined storage on an EMC array.

Any compatibility issues with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?   I would like to install Openstack on this environment.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Best
Larry

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the requirements for openstacks.
Visit https://www.ubuntu.com/openstack/install

Hope you´d install it!